# Vue 3 Foreach tabs slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some issues foreaching Vue 3 tabs with bulma ui.
So I want to foreach them beacuse it will be same form for all of them, and here it how looks:

```
const languages = [
  { label: 'Serbian', value: 'rs' },
  { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
  { label: 'Bulgarian', value: 'bg' },
  { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
  { label: 'Romanian', value: 'ro' },
  { label: 'Albanian', value: 'al' }
]
```

and I'm listing them like:

```
<VTabs
    slider
    type="rounded"
    selected="en"
    :tabs="languages"
  >
<template #tab="{ activeValue }">
      <div v-if="activeValue === 'rs'">
        <VField label="Title">
          <VControl>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="input"
              placeholder="Product Title"
            />
          </VControl>
        </VField>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="activeValue === 'bg'">
        <VField label="Title">
          <VControl>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="input"
              placeholder="Product Title"
            />
          </VControl>
        </VField>
      </div>
    </template>
</VTabs>
```

But I can't find proper way to foreach them by language, I tried putting foreach in template, in div bellow template and nothing works. Any suggestions?